# Euler's Theorem proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Is my proof of Euler's theorem correct ?

**Euler's Theorem.** For any positive integers $a$ and $m$, if $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then
$$a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}.$$ 
*Proof.* Let $r_1, r_2, r_3, \dots, r_{\phi(m)}$ be the integers less than or equal to $m$ that are relatively prime to it. The integers
$$(1)\qquad ar_1, ar_2, ar_3, \dots, ar_{\phi(m)}$$
are congruent to 
$$(2)\qquad r_1, r_2, r_3, \dots, r_{\phi(m)}$$
in some order. The reason behind this is that if, say for some $1\leq k\leq \phi(m)$, $ar_k$ is congruent to some least residue $j$ modulo $m$ where $\gcd(m,j)>1$, then that would imply either $\gcd(m, r_k)>1$ or $\gcd(m, a)> 1$, both of which contradict our initial assumption. To show that (1) are congruent to all the integers in (2), suppose that
$$ar_j\equiv ar_i\pmod{m}$$
Since $\gcd(a,m)=1$ and $r_j$ and $r_k$ are least residues, it follows that
$$r_j\equiv r_i\pmod{m}$$
$$r_j=r_m.$$
Multiplying all the integers in (1), we obtain
$$a^{\phi(m)}r_1r_2r_3\dots r_{\phi(m)}\equiv r_1r_2r_3\dots r_{\phi(m)}\pmod{m}.$$
Since $\gcd(r_1r_2\dots r_{\phi(m)}, m)=1$, we can cancel the common factor to get
$$a^{\phi(m)}=1\pmod{m}.\quad\square$$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you! :)  .